# change/forgot password with a hashed password possible?

Tags: asp.net, hash, forgot-password, change-password

i have implemented my user passwords to be hashed. And what i want is to implement a forgot/change password. However i am not able to convert the hashed password to the original password and that gives me a failure to do the forgot/change password feature. Here is my code from my registration page:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", BusinessLayer.ShoppingCart.CreateSHAHash (txtPW.Text));
```

Here is my creathash code:

```
public static string CreateSHAHash(string Phrase)
    {
        SHA512Managed HashTool = new SHA512Managed();
        Byte[] PhraseAsByte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Concat(Phrase));
        Byte[] EncryptedBytes = HashTool.ComputeHash(PhraseAsByte);
        HashTool.Clear();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(EncryptedBytes);
    }
```

and my changepassword page:

```
protected void btn_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
        con.Open();
        str = "select * from UserData ";
        com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (txt_cpassword.Text == reader["Password"].ToString())
            {
                up = 1;
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
        con.Close();
        if (up == 1)
        {
            con.Open();
            str = "update UserData set Password=@Password where UserName='" + Session["New"].ToString() + "'";
            com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
            com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500));
            com.Parameters["@Password"].Value = (txt_npassword.Text);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            lbl_msg.Text = "Password changed Successfully";
        }
        else
        {
            lbl_msg.Text = "Please enter correct Current password";
        }
    }
```

What i want to do is to be able to convert my hashed password to the original password for it to be changed. Any tricks? or is it possible though?

Comment: Why do you need the old password to replace it with a new password? Why can't you just overwrite the old password with the new password?

Comment: Note - hashing is a one-way function. You cannot get the original string from a hashed string. This is in contrast to encryption, where you *can* get the original string from an encrypted string. However, passwords should always be stored *hashed* NOT *encrypted* as this is more secure (an attacker who obtains your database file and hashing mechanism cannot trivially obtain the plain-text passwords)

Comment: @RB. good idea. any documentation you can share with me sir?

Comment: Errr...what sort of documentation are you looking for? I've just described a high-level concept...

Comment: @RB. any idea on how to do it sir? delete statement?

Comment: look at http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity   and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d94bdzz2(v=vs.110).aspx  for ideas